# Suspect UDP traffic on lo interface

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, udp

I'm monitoring the lo interface with iptraf and am getting a lot of movement in the following form:

`UDP (268 bytes) from 127.0.0.1:49254 to 127.0.0.1:49254 on lo`

This message appears on average every 1-1.5 seconds.

I have tried to search the internet to understand what is generating these packets but without luck.

I have also tried to issue a

`netstat | grep 49254` to try and see what is generating this traffic but with no luck. besides this I have run a `ps -aux | grep more` and went through every process to try and spot  if there are any suspect executable files running but no luck there too.

Would apreciate some suggestions on how to track down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command 'ss -aupn | grep 49254' has a decent chance of showing you what is generating that traffic.

Comment: Got it. It our postgresql db server.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/), it will provide you information which process is sending those packets.